# How to make .Net Core 2.x as default?

Tags: windows, .net-core

I am on Windows 10. I have both `.net core` 2.1 and 5.0 installed on my machine. I can see them in path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`. Also both of them are present in the result of the following command:

```
dotnet --info
```

When running `dotnet --version` on the prompt I see version 5.0.401. I have some backward compatiblites, so I need to use `.net core 2.1` only.

How can I make `.net core 2.1` as default? Please consider that I mean `cli`. On the other hand, I want `.net core 2.x` be run everytime I type `dotnet` in the terminal.

**UPDATE**

1. re-installing .net sdk 2.1 didn't help
2. when in the windows 'settings => Apps & features' search for `core` I see only `2.1`. However, when searching for SDK, I can see both `.Net Core SDK 2.1` and `.NET SDK 5.0`. Do you remember that `core` has been removed from the product name? I tried to remove 5.0 but got message: .NET SDK 5.0 was installed with Visual Studio. So use Visual Studio Modify. But Visual Studio modify page does not have such a option. It only allows .Net Core 2.1 removal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *global.json* file to specify the version you would like to use. You can do so within the folder where your project is, or add one on a higher level to for instance have it work for your entire `code` folder.

> On rare occasions, you may need to use an earlier version of the SDK. You specify that version in a [global.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json). The "use latest" policy means you only use global.json to specify a .NET SDK version earlier than the latest installed version.
>
> *global.json* can be placed anywhere in the file hierarchy. The CLI searches upward from the project directory for the first *global.json* it finds. You control which projects a given *global.json* applies to by its place in the file system. The .NET CLI searches for a *global.json* file iteratively navigating the path upward from the current working directory. The first *global.json* file found specifies the version used. If that SDK version is installed, that version is used. If the SDK specified in the *global.json* isn't found, the .NET CLI uses [matching rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#matching-rules) to select a compatible SDK, or fails if none is found.
>
> The following example shows the global.json syntax:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "sdk": {
>    "version": "2.1.30"
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> The process for selecting an SDK version is:
>
> - dotnet searches for a *global.json* file iteratively reverse-navigating the path upward from the current working directory.
> - dotnet uses the SDK specified in the first *global.json* found.
> - dotnet uses the latest installed SDK if no *global.json* is found.

For more information, see [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version).

Comment: Please consider that I mean cli. On the other hand, I want .net core 2.x be run everytime I type dotnet in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

All .NET versions get installed to the same location. When you type `dotnet`, the latest SDK/Runtime/host is used (unless you override it per-project).

So, if you really want `dotnet` to mean .NET Core 2.1 and nothing else, the right way to do that seem to be to uninstall newer versions such as .NET 5.

Comment: It wasn't possbile to remove .NET 5. Please see my 2nd update

Comment: I correct. It is possible to remove .NET 5. One just should open `Individual components` tab not just the `Workloads`.